# why feed importer cron fails?

Tags: feeds, cron

In my drupal 6 website, we have used feed importers to import feed, but from few days We are not getting new feeds and then I have gone to 'status report' in admin panel and checked status report & I found that cron is not running.As I have seen that there is problem in cron I imported feed manually and it worked for me.

When I tried to run feed import cron manually from status report page I got error "cron run failed"

As I am new to Drupal, I dont know that from where I should start cron failed troubleshooting.

Can anyone suggest me the way.

Comment: Have you updated any modules recently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer to this problem.

I used debug code `if ($hook == 'cron') watchdog('cron', "hit $module cron");` in `function module_invoke_all()`

where to put debug code ?

In module.inc file of core drupal, add

```
 $function = $module .'_'. $hook;
 $result = call_user_func_array($function, $args);
```

between this two line of module_invoke_all() function, add above debug line.

It will look like :

```
$function = $module .'_'. $hook;

if ($hook == 'cron') watchdog('cron', "hit $module cron"); 

$result = call_user_func_array($function, $args);
```

After putting above line in module.inc,run cron manually and check log in recent log entries.

Because of this debug statement, I found the module which was not allowing to run cron.

I corrected the custom module code in that and cron started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

My best bet would be to check the server log files (apache or nginx, depends on what you are using). You can usually do that in the hosting admin panel or by going to the server directly via ssh.